# Why does bootstrap use '!important' for responsive classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap responsive utilities are all using `!important`, which doesn't make much sense to me. And it doesn't do inheritance like `col-xx-xx` does. I'd like to know why they added `!important` for these classes. Someone mentioned it was for specificity. What does that mean? In addition, show and hide classes seems to use `!important` as well. Why?

Comment: I don't see any `!important` in the latest tag of TB3 (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css line 1313) What version are we talking about?

Comment: ah, you are right. I'll change my question little bit. Ignore the text alignment,  look at responsive utilities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While using `!important` is rarely a good idea as you noticed yourself, since it is a pain to overwrite without using `!important` yet again, I believe TB has a good reason for doing this for the responsive utilities.

If you state that you want e.g. a button to be not visible on e.g. small displays, by setting the `hidden-sm` class to that button, you never want it to be visible on small displays. If you would not use important on that utility class, and you would e.g. want a block button on all the other display sizes by adding `.btn-block` class, your button would become visible again on small displays, since the `.btn-block` sets the `display` property back to `block`. Or at least it could, depending on the order of things, since `.hidden-sm` and `.btn-block` have the same specificity when it comes to the cascading rules of css.

Nothing much you can do about that without the `!important` statement. So this is one of the edge cases where you would have to use it to guarantee the correct behavior.

But you are right in questioning this, `!important` should only be used as a last resort!

Comment: Thank you Pevara, that's the case I didn't think of. An alternative way might be moving all utilities to the end of css order. That would override most of the other global specificity or general utilities. The part I don't like is most of responsive class doesn't have inheritance. ex: hidden-xs would only hide element on xs view, it doesn't extend to -md and larger view. They are way too specified. Maybe they designed this way because of '!important' shouldn't be inherited.

Comment: Hey @pevara, why do you think bootstrap responsive utilities are so specific for different media view size? why not make class inheritable like col-sm-xx, it inherits to lg size.

Comment: My solution instead of using `!important` is opting for higher specificity, ie. `.hidden-sm.hidden-sm { // hide styles }`
Can get unwieldy too (ie. 3, 4 or more levels), but is certainly better than throwing `!important` everywhere